# How did they come up with the inequality for the multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, absolute-value

I am trying to figure out how in my answers sheet they got the approximation of the function $$g(x,y)=\frac{y}{1+x^2+y^2}$$
to
$$\mid{g(x,y)} \mid  \leq \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{1+x^2+y^2} $$

Is it simply because $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is a positive number and thus y is smaller than something added to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because$$\lvert y\rvert=\sqrt{y^2}\leqslant\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Since $$|g(x,y)|=\frac{|y|}{1+x^2+y^2}$$ and $$|y|\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
you will get your inequality.